# How to solve the two dimension Poisson equation with a Dirac delta function.

Tags: boundary-value-problem

The equation is from the paper "Point defect sink efficiency of low-angle tilt grain boundaries".
I get confused that the author get  a solution without firstly giving the boundary condition.

the equation is
$$\Delta c=\delta(\Gamma)$$ and $\delta(\Gamma)$ is the Dirac delta function of $\Gamma$ $$\delta(\Gamma) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\delta\left(y-jp\right)$$

they have one solution periodic in y ,
$$c(x,y)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln(2\cosh\frac{2\pi x}{p}-2\cos\frac{2\pi y}{p})+C$$ C is a constant. I can't get the solution while the author didn't put the proof on appendix. I've try WKB theory or boundary layer theory but no useful

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the paper don't give the boundary conditions firstly, but you can read the paper to get detailed information from Non-irradiation promblem.